# Why is the C# parsed DateTime 7 hours ahead?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, iso, gmt

In trying to convert my local time from Javascript to C# I've poked around S/O to find some examples. While I've found a few different approaches to this, all of them render the final time as 7 hours ahead of me, which I'm not understanding.

e.g.:

```
var t = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(1468877118719).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(t)
7/18/2016 9:25:18 PM//<--output
```

or

```
var t = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-18T21:27:32.513Z");
Console.WriteLine(t);
7/18/2016 9:27:32 PM//output
```

Also, even when I simply try

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(now);
7/18/2016 9:39:55 PM//the output is 7 hours ahead.
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to rectify it?

Comment: anytime you get an unexpected date/time difference that's some exact numbers of hours out, it's almost always a timezone issue. no doubt your computer is in UTC+7 for the timezone

Comment: You're treating a local time as a UTC time.  Don't do that (or get a UTC time, rather than a local time, as your input).

Comment: DateTimeKind.Utc is your problem here. Get it in local time.

Comment: @MarcB do you know if this is something I can simply change in settings to correct the issue?

Comment: not really. changing it for this usage case could break lots of other things. you should always know what TZ a particular date/time value is in, and tell the system about it. never let it try to GUESS what you mean, because it'll invariably guess wrong.

Comment: You got something going wrong if that last one is off by 7 hours. Check your time zone and regional settings. If this is running on a server, check that. I just ran that same code locally and got the correct local time.

Answer (score 2):

The machine where you run this has its local clock set to match UTC.

This is very common on servers and *nix workstations, including OS X.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the output of the UTC value.

Change

```
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine(t.ToLocalTime());
```

Of course, this will only make a difference in the second case. You're already calling `ToLocalTime()` in the first instance.

Comment: @spb: Then that's probably because the current time zone of the context of the code *is* UTC see here: [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O7Ve16)